# How to change time format to another format?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date string value

```
let stringData = '2020/01/06 Mon 17:30';
```

I want to change the date string becomes to `2020-01-06 17:30:00`

Here is what I try:

```
import momentTimezone from 'moment-timezone';

let stringData = '2020/01/06 Mon 17:30';

stringData = momentTimezone(stringData).tz('Asia/Taipei').format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
```

but `console.log(stringData)` shows `Invalid date`

then I try:

```
start_time = moment(stringData, "YYYY/MM/DD ddd").format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss");
```

get `2020/01/06 00:00:00`

Is any way achieve it ?

Comment: Use the correct parse format string: YYYY/MM//DD ddd HH:mm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

showing Invalid date because you are including day in you date string

let stringData = '2020/01/06 17:30';

moment(stringData ,"YYYY-MM-YY HH:mm:ss")

Comment: I try to use `start_time = moment(stringData, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss");` and it works, thanks for your help.

Comment: The OP should use the correct parse format string, the one suggested here does not match the string to be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working [example](https://codepen.io/rainercedric23/pen/WNbdjYv)

You can just remove the `Mon` since the day is already included on the date.

Comment: Thanks for your help, remove `Mon` is not good for my project logic. I will try to use `moment(stringData, dateFormat)`

Comment: I've tried adding `Mon` and moment can still parsed the date correctly. You can just change the `YY` to `DD`